# Redis failover scenario

Tags: redis, servicestack.redis

currently I have a redis instance, now I would make it more failure prove.
Is it possible to archive the following things?
I connect to redis with the service stack library, now I want that when the server is not available redis switch to the failover server automatically.

Comment: // , Would you please edit this for better English?

Answer (score 0):

You should configure a Redis instance as a slave of your master instance, either using the slaveof command or more likely by adding a slaveof directive in the configuration file (something like 'slaveof 127.0.0.1 6380' ; look at the [documentation](http://redis.io/topics/config) for more info); then use [Redis Sentinel](http://redis.io/topics/sentinel) to monitor the instances and promote the Slave as Master when the master fails.

Moreover you either have to use a [Redis client](http://redis.io/clients) that [supports sentinel](http://redis.io/topics/sentinel-clients) and handles the redirection when the slave is promoted to slave, or use a network configuration (like virtual IP) to make the redirection transparent for your application.